# easy way to link an (offline) payment to a participant

Tags: payment-processor, paylater

we are not using any CC payment but rely stricktly on bank transfer or cash payment. Especially with these bank transfer payments it takes time to link payments to event participants.

It would help if each participant could be given a unique payment reference of some kind to include in the comment of their bank transfer so linking that payment to an event participant would become easier.

Is this possible in Civi? or through an extension?

Comment: Maarten, can you tell us a little more about the version you are using and where you are based? Financial solutions differ sometimes per world region. So you might be interested in something like CiviSepa if you are based in Europe?

Comment: I am also interested in a solution to this problem. Maarten, what solution have you used ?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand the question 100%, but Civi can be configured with ACH payment processing (e.g. using iATS: http://home.iatspayments.com/) - this will allow for users to register themselves online and will link the event payment with the participant record. For cash payments, you can use "Pending (Pay Later)" either from the front end (by enabling this as an option in the event configuration on the amounts tab - e.g. pay at the door) or back end (creating a back office registration and recording a contribution with a status of pending pay later).

[image]

Hope this helps!
Tamar

Comment: Hi Erik, we're based in Belgium. And it's very common for a any bank payment request you receive from e.g. your mobile Phone subscription or water service, that they all have an automatically generated numer on the statement. You specify that at the time of you payment and the companies system can link your payment to your bill automatically. I would like to generate such a number on our booking confirmation emails, so people also use that number in their payment. That makes it much easier to link their bank payment to a booking instead of having to compare name. That makes sense at all?

Comment: Hi Tamar, we are only a very small non profit organisation, really only using Civi because of it's flexibility to create events and allow our members to book participation following the custom forms we create. But we don't have the means to go support online payments using CC as those fees are to high. So most members choose to "pay later" and pay via a bank transfer using the info we provide in the email. we're looking for an easier way to link those (offline I believe Civi calls that) payments to the event participant record instead of name since participant and sponsor don't Always match

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the additional info. If I understand correctly, you essentially want to provide those who pay via bank draft a reference number such that when you are informed of the receipt of a payment by your bank, you can do a find on the number and pull up the pending pay later contribution more easily than you would just by relying on a name - if that's the case, I would suggest you add a token to the for contribution ID and/or contact ID in the "Contributions - Receipt (on-line)" System Workflow Message Template provides content and formatting for the receipt. You can modify it from Administer > Communications > Message Templates > System Workflow Message and it is part of the email that they receive after registering and ask that they include that as a memo or a note when requesting the bank transfer. You will need knowledge of HTML to do this (which I do not have).

The link to the participant record will be preserved if you edit the pending pay later contribution to a status of "Completed" and include whatever other details of the payment that are pertinent (e.g. transaction numer, date, etc.).

Hope this helps,
Tamar